# How to change font size for labels values of bars in QML Bar Chart of Qt Charts?

Tags: qt, qml

I create a Bar Chart like this:

```
ChartView {
    id: barChartView
    ...
}
```

then function

```
function drawBar(){
    barChartView.removeAllSeries();
    barChartView.titleFont = Qt.font({bold:true,pixelSize:20});

    var barAbstractSeries = barChartView.createSeries(ChartView.SeriesTypeBar); // AbstractSeries object
    barAbstractSeries.clear();
    barAbstractSeries.append(qsTr("Resource Consumption"),getData());
    barAbstractSeries.labelsVisible = true;
    barAbstractSeries.labelsAngle = 270;
    barAbstractSeries.barWidth = 0.8;
    //barAbstractSeries.labelsPosition = AbstractBarSeries.LabelsOutsideEnd;

    barChartView.axisX().categories = getCats();
    barChartView.axisX().labelsAngle = 270;
    barChartView.axisX().labelsFont = Qt.font({bold:true,pixelSize:15});
    barChartView.axisX().gridLineColor = "#b1b1b1";
    barChartView.axisY().gridLineColor = "#b1b1b1";
    ...        
}
```

Result:

QML QT Charts Bar chart

[image]

I need to set bold style, font size for values in bars.
I not found info in [manual for BarSeries](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-barseries-members.html)
and other manuals. Maybe this is written elsewhere, but I did not find it and I would be grateful if someone helped me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, you can create a Abstract Series dinamically using the function [createSeries](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-chartview.html#createSeries-method). You create an [AbstractBarSeries](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-abstractbarseries.html) that is conformed by a set of [BarSet](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-barset.html#details).

The BarSet has different properties, I think you are looking for [labelColor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-barset.html#labelColor-prop) property and the [labelFont](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtcharts-barset.html#labelColor-prop). You can modify the color, the size & style of the label easily by modifying this properties.

When you add the element that you want to stylise just modify the BarSet.

```
BarSet example = mySeries.append("example", data);
// now modify of the components the you want of BarSet
// Example modify the font with 15px and bold style
example.labelFont = Qt.font({pointSize: 15, bold:true});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function drawBar(){
    ...
    var barset = barAbstractSeries.append(qsTr("Resource Consumption"),getData());
    barset.labelFont = Qt.font({pointSize: 26, bold:true});
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is a pity that I can not mark both answers as a solution.

Comment: No problem, didn't saw someone answered already. Nice Chart! А как информацию со счетчиков снимаешь?

Comment: У нас проект, в котором участвуют счётчики с блоками телеметрии. К сожалению не имею права разглашать детали.